# How to append tee to a file in Bash?

Tags: bash, tee

These are commands I type in the terminal

```
echo -e "First Line" | tee ~/output.log
echo -e "Second Line" | tee ~/output.log
```

When I look in the file output.log I only see 'Second Line'. How can I make sure that tee appends (rather than wipes out the file)?

I'd like to be able to see this in the file:

```
First Line
Second Line
```

Should I be approaching this another way?

Answer (score 314, accepted):

```
echo -e "First Line" | tee ~/output.log
echo -e "Second Line" | tee -a ~/output.log
                            ^^
```

From [man tee](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tee.1.html):

```
   Copy standard input to each FILE, and also to standard output.

   -a, --append
          append to the given FILEs, do not overwrite
```

Note: Using `-a` still creates the file mentioned.

Comment: For the benefit of the searchers, the -a modifier is for 'append', or add to the end. Without -a, the tee command overwrites the file.

Comment: Does tee still create the file if it doesn't exist when the "-a" option is included?

Comment: @chili555: is it possible appending to the beginning of file, not to the end, and doesn't overwrite a file? Thanks.

Comment: @СашаЧерных None that I am aware of. That sounds like a great subject for a new question!

Comment: @Саша Черных 'cat source.file destination.file | tee destination.file' will append source.file at the beginning of destination.file. The only catch with this approach is that tee will print to stdout both files.

Comment: Is it possible to have `tee` append to a new line? I.e., to append after first inserting a line break to ensure subsequent outputs are each on new lines.

Comment: @wes `printf '\n' | tee -a ~/output.log`